# How can I loop through IEnumerble<Card> CreateDeck(); and print to the console?

Tags: c#, .net

So I recently wrote an algorithm which I posted on stack exchange/code review and it was very well received and I got loads of improvements suggested. I'm new to C# and I don't really understand the IEnumerable interface.

How do I print to the console my entire deck?

The code below is a method, if I call the method there is nothing else I can do... Or can I?

One of the Methods I was suggested to use is:

```
public IEnumerable<Card> CreateDeck()
{
  var deck = new List<Card>();

  foreach(var value in Enum.GetValues<CardValue>())
    foreach (var suit in Enum.GetValues<CardSuit>())
      deck.Add(new Card(value, suit));

  return deck;
}
```

**My Enums for Cards**

```
public enum CardValue {Ace, King, Queen, Jack, Ten, Nine, Eight, Seven, Six, Five, Four, Three, Two};
public enum CardSuit {Spades, Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds};
```

**Creating a Card**

```
public struct Card
{
  public CardValue Value { get; }
  public CardSuit Suit { get; }

  public Card(CardValue value, CardSuit suit)
  {
    Value = value;
    Suit = suit;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return $"{Value} of {Suit}";
  }
}
```

Comment: WIth a foeach loop just print all values one after another?

Comment: `foreach (var card in CreateDeck()) Console.WriteLine(card);`. You could also reduce memory requirements in `CreateDeck()` method by using `yield return` rather than using a `List`.

Comment: Wait I can use a method in a foreach loop?

Comment: yes the sky is the limit here, maybe add some brackets when you re on it (personal preference)

Comment: in fact .add() is a method so you have been doing it all along

Comment: @DenisSchaf An explicit `ToString()` is unnecessary; `Console.WriteLine` has an overload that accepts `object` and internally calls `ToString()`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks, was unaware! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var card in CreateDeck()) Console.WriteLine(card);
```

This uses the `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload, that will internally call the `ToString()` method defined on `Card`.

---

As an aside, you could reduce memory usage in your `CreateDeck` method by using `yield return` instead of allocating a list:

```
public IEnumerable<Card> CreateDeck()
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues<CardValue>())
    {
        foreach (var suit in Enum.GetValues<CardSuit>())
        {
            yield return new Card(value, suit);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, `Card`s are created on-demand as you iterate, and immediately become eligible for garbage collection after they leave scope.

If you find that you need a list, you can always do this:

```
var cards = CreateDeck().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement GetEnumerator method in CardDeck class or any class as

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cd = new CardDeck();
            cd.cards = new List<Card>()
                {
                    new Card(CardValue.Ace, CardSuit.Spades),
                    new Card(CardValue.Five, CardSuit.Clubs)
                };

            foreach (var c in cd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }

        }
    }
```

Above is example how to use in look

OP Code

```cs
    public enum CardValue { Ace, King, Queen, Jack, Ten, Nine, Eight, Seven, Six, Five, Four, Three, Two };
    public enum CardSuit { Spades, Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds };

    public struct Card
    {
        public CardValue Value { get; }
        public CardSuit Suit { get; }

        public Card(CardValue value, CardSuit suit)
        {
            Value = value;
            Suit = suit;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Value} of {Suit}";
        }
    }
```

IEnumerable implementation

```cs
    class CardDeck
    {
        public List<Card> cards;

        public IEnumerator<Card> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var contact in cards)
                yield return contact;
        }
    }
```